# How configure Amazon EFS as data volume in Elastic Beanstalk web application windows .NET instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, amazon-efs

I do have an .NET Application which I would like to deploy to Beanstalk. I would like to add an EFS to it. I tried but i did not was able to configure EFS with a windows Beanstalk.

How can I configure it?

I already tried adding .[config files to the .ebextensions directory](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html) , but nothing happens. I don't either see any errors on deployment. Neither the logs shows any EFS command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to persist files for a web application using Amazon AWS without a full VM?](https://serverfault.com/questions/850556/is-there-any-way-to-persist-files-for-a-web-application-using-amazon-aws-without)

Comment: I posted a link to [a guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/services-efs.html) in the last question you asked. Did you try it? If so, did it work? If not, exactly what happened? Using that technique you should be able to create a new or mount an existing EFS volume. The linked article has examples.

Comment: EFS is not officially supported yet on Microsoft Windows operating systems as there is no support for NFSv4. ELasticBeanStalk .NET apps run on top of Windows EC2 instances, so I am afraid that, at least until there is proper NFSv4 support in Windows Server, this feature won't be available.